# How to specify the Chrome binary location via the selenium server standalone command line?

Tags: google-chrome, selenium

I am using a portable version of Google Chrome that is not stored at the default location of my Windows 7 machine. I don't have admin rights to install Chrome at the default location.

Running `java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.52.0.jar -help` does not hint any possibility of setting the path to the **chrome binary** (**not the chrome driver**).

The [chrome driver capabilities](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities) indicate that it's possible to set the **binary** but I'm not sure how to do it via the command line.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can specify a non-standard location for the chrome binary in ChromeOptions.

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setBinary("/path/to/other/chrome/binary");
```

See the ChromeOptions documentation at: 
https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities#TOC-Using-a-Chrome-executable-in-a-non-standard-location

Answer (score 4):

After many tries I've found that configuration like (please scroll window with code to find property **chrome_binary**)

**For Windows environment**

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.52.0.jar 
  -role webdriver 
  -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="\path\to\chromedriver.exe"
  -browser "browserName=chrome,version=__version__,maxinstance=__no__,platform=WINDOWS,chrome_binary=\path\to\chrome\binary\chrome.exe" 
  -hubHost __address__
  -port __port__
```

works like a charm

Comment: You've no idea how much time I've wasted looking for this information!

Answer (score 2):

Use `-nodeConfig <JSON config file>` in the node and set the capabilities there

Example json file:

```
{
  "capabilities":
  [
    {
      "browserName": "chrome",
      "maxInstances": 5,
      "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver",
      "chrome_binary": "C:/Program Files/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe"
    }
  ],
  "maxSession": 5,
  "register": true,
  "registerCycle": 5000,
  "nodeStatusCheckTimeout": 5000,
  "nodePolling": 5000,
  "role": "node"
}
```

Note: This is for server version 3.x.x
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Grid2#configuring-the-nodes-by-json

Answer (score 2):

Specify the chrome binary location.

```
options = Options()
options.headless = True
options.binary_location = CHROME_BINARY
driver = webdriver.Chrome(CHROME_DRIVER, options=options)
```

Answer (score 0):

BinaryLocation should point to the exe of Chrome(the browser: chrome.exe!!! ), not chromedriver.exe

driverPath and driverExecutableFileName are pointing to the chrome DRIVER: chromedriver.exe

Answer (score 0):

Try this first:

```
export PATH=c:/sdk/chrome/App/Chrome-bin:$PATH; java ....
```

Answer (score -1):

The quick way that you should put your chromedriver into your selenium-server-standalone-2.52.0.jar the **same folder** .

Ex: XXX folder will have the jar and the driver exe

Comment: As stated in my question, this is not about the driver. It is about the Chrome binary (chrome.exe) itself

Comment: Using a Chrome executable in a non-standard location

ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setBinary("/path/to/other/chrome/binary");

Comment: @JosephMTsai I am getting this `AttributeError: 'Options' object has no attribute 'setBinary'`

Comment: chrome_options = Options()
 chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
 driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)

Comment: you could try this

Answer (score -1):

You can also use:

```
DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
capability.setCapability("chrome.binary","/path/to/chromedriver.exe);
driver = new ChromeDriver(capability);
```

from org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities

Comment: Unfortunately, you missed chromedriver.exe with Chrome browser binary in your answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.setBinary("/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome");
```

Answer (score -2):

First check chrome compatibility on http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/web/chromedriver/ , then download and place it

And then Start appium server with the following command:

appium --chromedriver-executable C:/Your path/chromedriver.exe

And run the script :)

Comment: This question didn't ask about appium, did it?

Comment: The question asked about Selenium Capability for pointing out to Chrome browser binary, i.e. to Chrome file location. In this answer chrome and chromedriver are messed.