# Selenium - Chrome binary ignored

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, chromium

I prefer to use old Selenium 2.53.1 with old version of Chromium 52.0 and chromedriver 2.24. I'm running following on Windows 7:

```
start java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=C:\dev\selenium\chromedriver.exe -Dwebdriver.chrome.binary=C:\dev\selenium\chrome-win32\chrome.exe -Dwebdriver.chrome.chrome_binary=C:\dev\selenium\chrome-win32\chrome.exe -Dwebdriver.chrome.capabilities.binary=C:\dev\selenium\chrome-win32\chrome.exe -Dwebdriver.chrome.capabilities.chrome_binary=C:\dev\selenium\chrome-win32\chrome.exe -browser browserName="chrome",version=ANY,platform=WINDOWS,maxInstances=1,binary="C:\dev\selenium\chrome-win32\chrome.exe",chrome_binary="C:\dev\selenium\chrome-win32\chrome.exe" -host 0.0.0.0 -port 4444
```

As you can see I have tried a lot of variants trying both `binary` and `chrome_binary`. But Selenium Server ignores those options and starts a default Chrome Browser. How to make it run the binary I specified `C:\dev\selenium\chrome-win32\chrome.exe`?

```
09:22:53.149 INFO - Launching a standalone Selenium Server
Setting system property webdriver.chrome.driver to C:\dev\selenium\chromedriver.exe
Setting system property webdriver.chrome.binary to C:\dev\selenium\chrome-win32\chrome.exe
Setting system property webdriver.chrome.chrome_binary to C:\dev\selenium\chrome-win32\chrome.exe
Setting system property webdriver.chrome.capabilities.binary to C:\dev\selenium\chrome-win32\chrome.exe
Setting system property webdriver.chrome.capabilities.chrome_binary to C:\dev\selenium\chrome-win32\chrome.exe
09:22:53.480 INFO - Java: Oracle Corporation 25.65-b01
09:22:53.480 INFO - OS: Windows 7 6.1 amd64
09:22:53.490 INFO - v2.53.1, with Core v2.53.1. Built from revision a36b8b1
09:22:53.569 INFO - Driver class not found: com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver
09:22:53.569 INFO - Driver provider com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver is not registered
09:22:53.579 INFO - Driver provider org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver registration is skipped:
registration capabilities Capabilities [{browserName=safari, version=, platform=MAC}] does not match the current platform VISTA
09:22:53.579 INFO - Driver class not found: org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver
09:22:53.579 INFO - Driver provider org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver is not registered
09:22:53.928 INFO - RemoteWebDriver instances should connect to: http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub
09:22:53.928 INFO - Selenium Server is up and running
09:22:54.331 INFO - Executing: [new session: Capabilities [{acceptSslCerts=false, browserName=chrome, platform=ANY}]])
09:22:54.345 INFO - Creating a new session for Capabilities [{acceptSslCerts=false, browserName=chrome, platform=ANY}]
Starting ChromeDriver 2.24.417431 (9aea000394714d2fbb20850021f6204f2256b9cf) onport 4923
Only local connections are allowed.
09:22:55.137 INFO - Done: [new session: Capabilities [{acceptSslCerts=false, browserName=chrome, platform=ANY}]]
```

Related (unaswered):

[How to specify the Chrome binary location via the selenium server standalone command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35776826/how-to-specify-the-chrome-binary-location-via-the-selenium-server-standalone-com)

Answer (score 0):

Change your command to something like below

```
start java  -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=C:\dev\selenium\chromedriver.exe
-Dwebdriver.chrome.binary=C:\dev\selenium\chrome-win32\chrome.exe
-Dwebdriver.chrome.chrome_binary=C:\dev\selenium\chrome-win32\chrome.exe
-Dwebdriver.chrome.capabilities.binary=C:\dev\selenium\chrome-win32\chrome.exe
-Dwebdriver.chrome.capabilities.chrome_binary=C:\dev\selenium\chrome-win32\chrome.exe 
-jar selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar -browser browserName="chrome",version=ANY,platform=WINDOWS,maxInstances=1,binary="C:\dev\selenium\chrome-win32\chrome.exe",chrome_binary="C:\dev\selenium\chrome-win32\chrome.exe" -host 0.0.0.0 -port 4444
```

and try again ? You should put the `-D` JVM argument before the `-jar`.

For more information refer [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html).

Comment: Thank you very much. I have tried, but still ignores my options and runs default Chrome Browser.

Comment: It is idiocy to allow to specify chrome binary from code. I don't need it.

Comment: Then you are better off taking it up with the Selenium codebase as a bug. I am only calling out what I am seeing from the codebase. Rest is upto you to decide on the further course of action.

Answer (score 0):

Seems using Selenium Grid everything works:

```
start java -Dwebdriver.server.session.timeout=900 -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar -role hub -host 0.0.0.0 -port 4444
start java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=C:\dev\selenium\chromedriver.exe -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar -role node -browser browserName="chrome",version=ANY,platform=WINDOWS,maxInstances=1,chrome_binary="C:\dev\selenium\chrome-win32\chrome.exe" -hub http://127.0.0.1:4444/grid/register -port 5555
```