# Selenium webdriver is looking at wrong path for Chrome.exe

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome

I am trying to launch chrome.exe from selenium webdriver i have chrome installed on my machine and chromedriver path is also given in code but selenium webdriver for java is looking for chrome.exe on wrong path and giving error and not launching browser.

I have tried options class to locate the chrome.exe with the actual path of chrome.exe but not working for me.I have done required imports as well but still no success.

I have tried below selenium webdriver java code

```
public class News24Test 

{

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception

  {


    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C://News24SA//ChromeDriver//chromedriver.exe");
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.setBinary("C://Program Files(x86)//Google//Chrome//Application//chrome.exe"); // Provide absolute executable chrome browser path with name and extension here
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("http://www.news24.com");

   }

}
```

Selenium is looking at below path which is wrong path
C:\Users\orestip\LocalSettings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

Comment: Do project clean before running it.

Comment: I tried the suggetion but it is not working for me. Any other way to make it work?

Comment: @abhijit where is your current Google Chrome directory? What is the error when you don't supply chrome binary location. Another solution for adding chrome binary https://stackoverflow.com/a/48230090/2466407

Comment: FYI: selenium will check your system PATH ..  you don't need to specify chromedrive's location in your code if it exists in a directory in your PATH environment variable.

Comment: I think you're using the wrong slashes there... you'll want backslashes... it's then falling back to your PATH var.

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the options first:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setBinary("C:\\Program Files(x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe");
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\News24SA\\ChromeDriver\\chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Comment: anyhow he's creating web-driver instance afterwards, I don't think this would make any impact.

Comment: @cruisepandey I thought it might have to do with the ChromeOptions being set on the default .exe

Comment: I tried the suggetions but they are not working for me. Any other way to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

**Make sure the chromedriver version and the chrome browers versions match.**

You can either update your chrome browser to match the driver version or you can choose a chromedriver that matches your browser version.

Answer (score 0):

Hi so old question but if anyone else is a bit stumped by this, I'll give my take.

So, you may one day have a working chromedriver and then it suddenly just stops working. What actually happens is Chrome updates behind the scenes and makes it out of date.

What you need to do is update your chromedriver so it matches your actual, normal Chrome installation.